# How to Dice Chain in Veggie Samurai?

Tags: ios, veggie-samurai

I know it's a silly question, but I just can't understand what breaks my "dice chain" in Veggie Samurai.
What is the correct move to chain the strokes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to **dice** a veg, you must slice it into 4 pieces which can be done by slicing it then slicing the two pieces which will return 4 pieces, that is referred as a **dice**. Breaking a dice chain can only happen if you have forgotten to dice or missed a veg, or even when the veg has been sliced into 3 pieces.

> Remember: Dice refers as a four sliced veg.